# Can't locate *** in @INC

Tags: perl

I install perl modules in `~/.local/perl5`. Here's part of `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="$HOME/.local/perl5";
export PERL_MB_OPT="--install_base $HOME/.local/perl5";
export PERL_MM_OPT="INSTALL_BASE=$HOME/.local/perl5";
export PERL5LIB="$HOME/.local/perl5/lib/perl5:$PERL5LIB";
export PATH="$HOME/.local/perl5/bin:$PATH";
```

I've installed `CSS::Inliner` with

```
$ cpan
cpan[1]> install CSS::Inliner
```

and I have `Inliner.pm` at:

```
~/.local/perl5/lib/perl5/CSS/Inliner.pm
```

But when I `use` it -- perl can't find it:

```
perl -e 'use Inliner'
```

gives:

```
Can't locate Inliner.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
/home/boris/.local/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-gnu-thread-multi
/home/boris/.local/perl5/lib/perl5 /etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5
/usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14
/usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at -e line 1. BEGIN failed--compilation
aborted at -e line 1.
```

why can't perl find the module?

**Edit**:

I'm trying to reproduce minimal working example given in documentation to [CSS-Inliner](http://search.cpan.org/~kamelkev/CSS-Inliner-3674/lib/CSS/Inliner.pm):

```
use Inliner;

my $inliner = new Inliner();

$inliner->read_file({filename => 'myfile.html'});

print $inliner->inlinify();
```

If I `use Inliner` -- perl can't find it. If I

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CSS::Inliner;

my $inliner = new Inliner();

$inliner->read_file({filename => 'test.html'});

print $inliner->inlinify();
```

perl says

```
Can't locate object method "new" via package "Inliner"
(perhaps you forgot to load "Inliner"?) at ./1.perl line 5.
```

**Edit 2**:

Here's a minimal working example of `CSS-Inliner`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CSS::Inliner;

my $inliner = CSS::Inliner->new;

$inliner->read_file({filename => 'test.html'});

print $inliner->inlinify();
```

Comment: @Mat: what do I do to install [CSS-Inliner](http://search.cpan.org/~kamelkev/CSS-Inliner-3674)? What should I `install` in `cpan`?

Comment: @Mat: see the edit to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the full module name in `use` and full class name when calling class methods:

```
use CSS::Inliner;
my $inliner = CSS::Inliner->new;
```

Comment: Despite the documentation which does indeed omit the `CSS::` prefix.

Comment: And you should [report a bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Create.html?Queue=CSS-Inliner) about that faulty documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen when you are not careful in installing modules.  Once I simply copied the foo.pm into the official /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl directory.  The foo.pm could be modules developed locally or third party.  I did not pay attention to the umask.  Files installed there are not readable by the world.  When I use the module I will get the message saying: Cannot locate foo.pm in @INC(@INC contains /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl ....). Gee it is clearly there!  Took me a while to check the file permission.  Hope this may save some time for others who install their own modules.  In make file you should use install -m 644 to make sure the installed module has read permission for others.